# Find local extrema of the following function.

Tags: real-analysis

> Find local extrema of the function $$u(x,y,z)=\sin x \cdot \sin y\cdot \sin z$$ with the condition $$x+y+z=\frac{\pi}{2};\; x,y,z>0$$

Can anyone give me pointers on how to solve this problem?

Comment: @MikePierce I formed the function $$F(x,y,z,\lambda)=\sin x ⋅\sin y⋅\sin z+\lambda \left(x+y+z-\frac{\pi}{2}\right) $$ and i found the derivatives of $F'_x,\; F'_y,\; F'_z\; \text{and}\; F'_\lambda$. Now I have to solve the system of equations: $$ F'_x= F'_y=F'_z= F'_\lambda=0$$. That's the part I really have no clue of how to solve.

Comment: The point is that you do not  really need Lagrange's multipliers (notice that the domain is not closed, too), just basic considerations.

Comment: Our TA has only explained this method of solving this kind of problem and on our exams we have to use Lagrange to solve the problem.

Comment: I will never understand the purpose of tying students' hands. Anyway, you may just eliminate $z$ and study a functions of two variables over a triangle. You have to study the boundary, since the domain is open, then to locate the stationary points inside by differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)$ is positive on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$, hence $\inf u=0$ and $u$ has no local minimum. On the other hand, by the AM-GM inequality and by the concavity of the sine function it follows that $x=y=z=\frac{\pi}{6}$ is the only local maximum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** By Jensen's inequality,
$$\sum \log(\sin x)\le 3\log(\sin \frac{x+y+z}3)$$

---

Or if you must use the Lagrangian, you get from first order conditions:
$$-\lambda = \cos x \sin y \sin z=\sin x \cos y \sin z = \sin x \sin y \cos z$$
$$\implies \tan x=\tan y =\tan z$$
$$\implies x = y=z\qquad\text{why?}$$
Hope you can fill in the rest...